# xcode Admob from unity issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine, admob

So Admob ads on Android are working fine but moving the project to iOS through xcode is having issues. I'm getting the following errors. (I'm using obj c as unity won't build to swift language).

```
2021-04-24 19:16:47.304948+0930 app[1083:230528] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process app
2021-04-24 19:16:47.305241+0930 app[1083:230528] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
2021-04-24 19:16:47.305493+0930 app[1083:230528] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO`
```

This is the first issue though I don't think this is what's stopping ads from showing as others have said their ads still show when this appears, but it shows everytime an ad is trying to receive.

```
2021-04-24 19:16:47.411615+0930 app[1083:230528] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=3 "Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing" UserInfo={RBSAssertionAttribute=<RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.webkit" name:"Background" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Target is not running or required target entitlement is missing}>`
```

This is the second issue, something about an entitlement somehwere, is there something I need to add to my plist file, this only comes up when I have admob etc in my project?

```
HandleRewardedAdFailedToLoad event received with message: Failed to receive ad with error: Request Error: No ad to show from all configured ad networks.
ADManager:HandleRewardedAdFailedToLoad(Object, AdErrorEventArgs)
System.EventHandler`1:Invoke(Object, TEventArgs)
System.EventHandler`1:Invoke(Object, TEventArgs)`
```

This is the big one, but not sure if it's because of the other errors? My ads on Android find ads every time no worries but on iOS it sends hundreds of requests and shows nothing from it.

Any thoughts would be amazing!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add capabilities to process in background and get remote notifications in background. You can do it like on screen:[image]